# Spring boot test mutliple projects with same bean name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have multiple spring projects as part of a single umbrella project. Two of them are `AuthServer` and `BackendApplication`. `AuthServer`, as name suggests is used only for auth purposes and rest is handled by `BackendApplication`. Now I am trying to write tests inside `BackendApplication` that also need to use auth related work. For that I have added `AuthServer` as a test dependency to `BackendApplication`. Now the problem is that, both projects have beans names `Utility` because of which I get DuplicateBeanException when I am including both contexts in my test. But I can disable any of them as they are necessary. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

Could you name your beans, for example:

```
@Bean(name = "my-utility-1")
public Utility createUtility1() {
  return new Utility();
}

// or

@Component(value = "my-utility-2")
public class Utility {
  ...
}
```

and refer to them by @Qualified

```
@Autowired @Qualified("my-utility-1")
private Utility myUtility;
```

Not related to your question, but i think you can mock `AuthServer` when testing `BackendApplication`.